# How do I create sub-classes in standard <style> tags?

Tags: html, css

For example, I may want to make create a `div.Style1` block where all `<img />` elements within this type of div are given certain properties.

Is this possible?
If so, what is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax is

```
 div.Style1 img { border: 3px red solid }
```

see also [CSS basics at W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)